# Removing curly brackets in an argument of ArcTan

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have list of number pairs

```
l = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}}
```

of which I want to take the ArcTan

```
ArcTan[l]
```

> ```
> {{π/4, 0}, {π/4, π/4}, {0, π/4}, {-(π/4), π/4}, {-(π/4), 0}, {-(π/4), -(π/4)}, {0, -(π/4)}}
> ```

This is not the desired answer because the curly brackets around the number pairs.

I solved it with

```
f[{x_, y_}] := ArcTan[x, y] 
f/@ l
```

> ```
> {0, π/4, π/2, (3 π)/4, π, -((3 π)/4), -(π/2)}
> ```

Is this the way to do this?

Comment: Use `ArcTan @@@ l` which is shorthand for `Apply[ArcTan, l, {1}]`

Answer (score 2):

Since `ArcTan` is `Listable`,

`ArcTan[{a,b,c}]`

is equivalent to

`{ArcTan[a], ArcTan[b],ArcTan[c]}`

and

`ArcTan[{{p, q}, {u, v}, {x, y}}]`

is equivalent to

`{{ArcTan[p], ArcTan[q]}, {ArcTan[u], ArcTan[v]}, {ArcTan[x], ArcTan[y]}}`

In Order to get the right result, `ArcTan` need to act directly on  `1,0` and `1,1` etc.

```
ArcTan@@@{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}}
```